# Regular Expression Match - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a RegEx that will match this:

`/Admin/doctemplate/edit/-537743660332489375`

And the id number at the end can change. Also a separate RegEx to match like so:

`/Admin/doctemplate/-537743660332489375/edit`

I have tried:

`/Admin/doctemplate/edit/[-0-9]+/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the regex for both cases:

```
/^\/Admin\/doctemplate\/(edit\/-?\d+|-?\d+\/edit)$/
```

with your two example:

```
/^\/Admin\/doctemplate\/(edit\/-?\d+|-?\d+\/edit)$/.test(yourString1) ->true
/^\/Admin\/doctemplate\/(edit\/-?\d+|-?\d+\/edit)$/.test(yourString2) ->true
```

if you want to use the test multiple times, better make it as a variable:

```
var re= new RegExp("^/Admin/doctemplate/(edit/-?\d+|-?\d+/edit)$")
re.test(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the forward slashes. Then you can use the digit class `\d` for the numbers (`[-0-9]+` would also match `0-4-6-58---458`, which I don't think you want).
1. `\/Admin\/doctemplate\/edit\/-\d+`
2. `\/Admin\/doctemplate\/-\d+\/edit`

I highly recommend [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) for messing with regex.